# Can Lulu app’s allowed/blocked apps lost be saved as a file?

Tags: macos

Does anybody know if its possible to save Lulu (https://objective-see.org/products/lulu.html) allowed/blocked apps as a configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the app saves them to a file and that import/export is a requested feature.

- https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu/issues/265